# Не работает hotkey

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-studio, hotkeys

Пересел в AndroidStudio на Ubuntu. И не работает корректно hotkey а именно Ctrl + Alt + L, которые по идее должны выравнивать код. Вместо этого отключается монитор на пару секунд.

Comment: В визуальной оболочке надо отключить этот хоткей.

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov можно чуточку поподробней )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас некоторые hotkey ведут себя "необычно", то скорей всего они используются Вашей визуальной оболочкой. 
В частности у меня это Unity. Чтобы посмотреть какая у Вас, откройте Terminal и введите следующую команду:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Далее заходим в наши "System Settings", где находим "Keybord". Нажимаем по иконке c клавиатурой, где видим два поля: "Typing" и "Shortcuts", нам нужно второе.
Перед Вами открывается диалоговое окно со множеством команд слева и горячими клавишами справа. Находим те которые используются системой, в моём примере это были Ctrl+Alt+L, и меняем на любые другие. 
Ура, теперь в Android Studio мы можем использовать этот hotkey.